# How do i trigger a method to bind data?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

How to bind a value in `data-toggle="buttons"` to an angular component variable

i tried to bind a value in `data-toggle="buttons"` to an angular component and to trigger a function but both did not work, The coding section i tried is below

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-dark" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : responseType==='direct'}">
    <input type="radio" name="responseType" autocomplete="off"
          (click)="selectResponseType('direct')"> Direct
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-dark" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : responseType==='fault'}">
    <input type="radio" name="responseType" autocomplete="off" 
           (click)="selectResponseType('fault')"> Fault
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-dark" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : responseType==='proxy'}">
    <input type="radio" name="responseType" autocomplete="off" 
           (click)="selectResponseType('proxy')"> Proxy
  </label>
</div>
```

i expect "responseType" variable in component should be set to the value of a selected option on selecting a radio option displayed as a button toggle, when i debugged it seems like it's not triggering the function or setting the binded value

Comment: you need to include bootstrap javascript as well

Comment: When do you load the Bootstrap Javascript file? If it is before the angular app render, It will not work. I suggest to use a Bootstrap library but in Angular way. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/